# Stop Prometheus client in python script

Tags: python, prometheus

Need to stop `prometheus_client.http_server` with Python code.

I have external Python application that is to be unit-tested. It has method that starts `prometheus_client` with `start_http_server(port)`. I need to unit-test it with several tests (indeed I don't test prometheus but other functionalities but can't take prometheus out of the code). As I need several tests so I need to start-stop method several times, but it exits after first attempt as Prometheus client is holding port and can't start again on the same port (`OSError: [Errno 48] Address already in use`).

The question: is there any way to stop `prometheus_client.http_server` with Python? Didn't find anything in `prometheus_client` docs about shutting it down...

Comment: My understanding, is that server started with `start_http_server` cannot be stopped. But you can expose metrics using your own server. You can make your own based on [current one](https://github.com/prometheus/client_python/blob/master/prometheus_client/exposition.py#L163).

Comment: Also, I'm not sure why couldn't your tests suppress start of server in the first place? You don't need to "take prometheus out of code" simply don't start server, and your problem should be solved.

Comment: start_http_server is inside of the outer module that I test - this is production code that I can't change. So I just import it to test. It starts without my permission =)

Comment: Well, in that case it would be incorrect to call it a unit testing, I believe. And regarding your problem, you'll need to start new process for every test (server will be automatically stopped with process), an your test couldn't be executed at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it's not exact answer to my question but anyway: I decided to `start_http_server = Mock(return_value=None)` so that it's not starting in unit-tests.

Answer (score 1):

You may use the following wrapper to start/stop Prometheus web-server ([solution source](https://github.com/prometheus/client_python/issues/76#issuecomment-1891040604)):

```py
import http
import http.server
import threading
from time import sleep

import prometheus_client


class CustomPrometheusHttpServer:
    def __init__(self, port):
        self.port = port
        self.httpd = None
        self.thread = None

    def start(self):
        self.httpd = http.server.HTTPServer(("0.0.0.0", self.port), prometheus_client.exposition.MetricsHandler)
        self.thread = threading.Thread(target=self.httpd.serve_forever)
        self.thread.daemon = True
        self.thread.start()

    def stop(self):
        if self.httpd:
            self.httpd.shutdown()
            self.httpd.server_close()
            self.httpd = None
        if self.thread:
            self.thread.join()
            self.thread = None


server = CustomPrometheusHttpServer(8080)
server.start()

sleep(10)
server.stop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to run the prometheus server with `wsgiref.simple_server.make_server` instead.
Then you should be able to invoke `.server_close()` on the server instance.

```py
from prometheus_client import start_http_server
from wsgiref.simple_server import make_server

# Start the server
port = 8000
httpd = make_server('', port, start_http_server)

# Stop the server
httpd.server_close()
```